# Can I suppress error occuring from iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, twitter, error-handling

I know how to suppress JavaScript errors(got source from [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/suppress.htm)):

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--
function silentErrorHandler() {return true;}
window.onerror=silentErrorHandler;
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

So, can I suppress error occuring from iframe? In my site, I'm using a [Twitter Widget](http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets), and it keeps making error boxes. If I can't suppress that error, I might have to remove the Twitter Widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. You cannot access websites not in the „same origin“ as your website (look for „same origin policy“)